# Redirect whole Subdirectory to Subdomain Subdirectory with .htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

Although I know a bit of RegEx I can't figure out, or find an answer here, on how to redirect subdirectory to **subdomain's subdirectory**. This is not a duplicate because every post here covers how to redirect subdirectory to subdomain. And the code, even after some modifications, doesn't work. So, here is an example:

Redirect all pages beginning with:

```
example.com/sub/directory/here/*
```

To the subdomain:

```
sub.example.com/directory/*
```

There also might be `www.` before the URLs. So, does anyone know how to do that, I'm struggling with this for hours :(. Explanation of code very welcome :) Any help much appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName example.com
ServerAlias *.example.com
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^sub.example.com$
RewriteRule ^sub/directory/here/(.*) http://sub.example.com/directory/$1 [R,L]
</VirtualHost>
```

**EDIT** If it is being used in a .htaccess then change to:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^sub.example.com$
RewriteRule ^/sub/directory/here/(.*) http://sub.example.com/directory/$1 [R,L]
```

Comment: Looked so promising :( Doesn't work, might be my fault, probably is my fault, so I want to know: I pasted this into `.htaccess` in the root folder of my website, does it matter where I put it since the paths are relative? I skipped the VirtualHost, ServerName, ServerAlias because I don't know what they do and I'm scared to use them and I skipped RewriteEngine on because I already have it in my code. Thanks for this so far, may I ask you to explain the code parts mentioned a bit? Thanks a ton! :)

Comment: Ok, if its in .htaccess then change the rewrite rule to the edit above